# Face Detection - Check if Face in VideoCapture is same as Pictures

Tags: python, image, opencv, face-recognition, face-detection

I am creating a Python face detection program that takes a VideoCapture. The code is below:

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = "C:/Pics"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

There are 3 pics in the directory of 3 different people (me, elon musk, jeff bezoz).

The above code only captures the video, but I want the Python program to check all the 3 pics and see whose pic matches with the VideoCapture. How do I do this?

Comment: You need to build that functionality yourself or use a third-party solution.

Comment: Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to search for face recognition. Dlib library is good choice

Comment: if you use `Google` to search `python face detect` then you should find many examples how to do it. And you get it much faster then asking on Stackoverflow. This way you may even find some examples in answers on Stackoverflow.  Yesterday I saw question which was using [deepface](https://github.com/serengil/deepface)

Comment: using Google I found this on blog PyImageSearch: [OpenCV Face Recognition - PyImageSearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/). This blog has many interesting posts.

Comment: This is not  CascadeClassifier cascPath = "C:/Pics".  You used this cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"